# List<?> adding and removing elements

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm currently programming a bukkit plugin (bukkit is a minecraft server type ;) ) and there, you've got a method in a class named [YamlConfiguration](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/configuration/file/YamlConfiguration.html) that has following method:

```java
public List<?> getList(String path)
```

My problem is: I'd like to add and/or remove elements from this list returned. But when I try to do this via

```java
YamlConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.load("path/to/config.yml");
config.getList("a.path").add(new String("foo"));
```

eclipse is throwing an error because

> The method add(capture#2-of ?) in the type List<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

I really don't know what to do. ^^'

Regards.

Comment: Figure out what type the elements in the List are. You should add an element of the same type (which obviously isn't String).

Comment: If you have a list of an unbounded type (`<?>`), you can't add anything to it, and you can get any type of `Object` from it. You need to bound the type. Try `List<String>`.

Comment: @StijnHaus The elements are Strings. I did save them as `List<String>` into this file and would like to get them returned as `List<String` not as `List<?>`... (Pastebin post: [link](http://pastebin.com/N4JyqMSa))

Comment: @JanDvorak If I do that by changing my code to `List<String> list = (List<String>) config.getList("a.path")`, eclipse says:

Type safety: Unchecked cast from List<capture#1-of ?> to List<String>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really want to load your item with `getList`? There's also [`getStringList(...)`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getStringList%28java.lang.String%29) available.

So maybe you could try:

```
config.getStringList("a.path").add("foo");
```

Comment: `add(new String("foo"))` -> `add("foo")`

Comment: @BGR yes, sure :) I was just changing my code to `add(new String())` and then remembered of something to write inside

Comment: @BGR Thanks for pointing out. I've edited my answer according.

Answer (score 2):

`List<?> list` can point to a List of any type, eg `List<String`> or `List<Integer`> or any other. That means you dont know what the actual list is, so you are allowed to add only `null` to this list. Read more in this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 0):

`?` is wildcard which represents an unknown type, because you don't know the type of `list<?>` so you can't add any element into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it returns a list of String, you can cast it:

```
((List<String>)config.getStringList("a.path")).add("foo");
```

Comment: if you use `getStringList`, you don't have to use the cast to `List<String>`... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace `<?>`  with `<Object>` then you can add any think like `Integer`,`String`,etc to your list ...

good luck :)